# Laravel 5.2 - Multiple relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Given this table structure:

[image: Table structure]

I have a `members` relation on my model.

```
public function members() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'group_members')->withPivot('status', 'right_rid')->withTimestamps();
}
```

When I call this function it will return the members of a specific function.

Now I want to call a function called `rights` or something like that, which will return the `right_id` and the type of the `rights` table in a single line of code.

Now when I want the `right_id` of a member I use this line:

```
$group->members->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->pivot->right_id
```

But then I don't have the `rights` type because the `right_id` is in the `group_members` table.

I want it to work something like this:

```
$group->members->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->rights
```

I hope that this is enough information to give me some advice, or even a solution for this problem.

I know this could also be done by making a custom query, but I like the way Laravel works.

Comment: I've fixed up some of your terms, should be okay.

Comment: Just at first glance in your DB structure image you have `rights_rid` but then you are showing in your code `right_id`.

Comment: Also you have `withTimestamps()` when none of your tables have timestamps.

Comment: Can you explain your current table structure (in words) and/or how you envision the relationships working (in words)? `group_members` just looks like a mistake - you're essentially assigning rights to the **link** between a user and a group. I'd expect rights to belong to either a user or a group. Not sure what you're aiming for...

Answer (score -1):

You could easily make a `GroupMember` model and do something like the following...

```
GroupMember::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('group_id', $group_id)->with(['rights', 'groups', 'users'])->get();
```

This assumes you have a `rights`, `groups`, and `users` method all in your `GroupMember` model.  Each of these should be a `belongsTo`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've created a GroupMember model. And now it works, and I made a BelongsTo relation to the User model form the GroupMember, and when I call member on a group, it will give met the record of that user in that group, thats normal. And when I want to get the users name form it, I need to call the belongsto relation in the user-function in GroupMember Model. But is there a method which allows me to combine these to in 1?

Comment: Yeah, you can pass an array into the `with` function.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'll call $group->members()->with(['user'])->get() and it gives the data, but how can I put a new record like that?